# Is it possible to nest JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object, nested

It seems that this is not possible. Is there another neat way of accomplishing this?

```
// Our transitions class
function Transitions() {
    this.fade = function() {
            this.create = function() {
                alert('you have arrived at the create method of the fade class');
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible. The way you are using it now.

You can do this to call a create function:

```
var x = new Transitions();
// Here .create does not exists
x.fade(); // Here the create function will be generated to the this object
x.create(); // Does alert
```

But you probably want something like this:

```
function Transitions() {
        // Create an object with an sub object
        this.fade = {
                create : function() {

                    alert('you have arrived at the create method of the fade class');
                }
        }

    }

var x = Transitions();
x.fade.create(); // Call the sub object
```

Comment: aah, so the colon instead of equal sign makes the entire difference, cool.

Comment: @MattiasSvensson well, in Niels example, fade is an object, not a function

Comment: True, I have changed `this.fade` from a function into an object by using the `{ }`, if I would use the `[]` it would be an array.